# PyQt5 from apt install python3-pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyqt5, debian

here is the error.

```
QWebView is not defined
```

I am following along from a PyQt4 tutorial at https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Embedding%20Widgets%20in%20Web%20Pages.

I understand defining but what exactly should I define here and where should I define it?

Where would I install QWebView?

I know the link provided is a PyQt4 example and I am using PyQt5. I know there have been changes but I have not found exactly what the answer could be now.

Comment: add `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *`

Comment: Thank you...I will test it.